# django fixtures with default value in

Tags: python, django

Can I use default value in django fixtures?
I want to change primary_key to uuid_key

```
class hogeModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

```
[
  {
    "model": "app.hogeModel",
    "pk": "",
    "fields": {
     "name": "hogehoge"
    }
  }
]
```

It's hard to make uuid every time.
Can't I fixtures without making a primary_key?

Waiting for your answer!!

Comment: or can set it to null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass 1, 2, 3... as primary key parameter by running an increment loop on your data and loading pk or else you can also try of using

```
"pk: null"
```

**EDIT**:

1. You can **loop** over your data and populate that Field.
2. Consider Django signals to populate the default you mentioned : something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25725567/8865579).

Comment: sorry, I can't your answer. `"pk": "null"` make uuid_pk??